# Httpservlet seems not to be included, but it is in the Build Path

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, servlets

I have the error:

```
The superclass "javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet" was not found on the Java Build Path
```

In the Java Build Path, there is Apache Tomcat 8, which has servlet-api.jar

even if I manually include this JAR, the error remains there.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you manually fiddle around in project's *Build Path* property? You should never have the need to do that to add/remove libs (at most to attach source or change ordering). In project's properties, check *Targeted Runtimes*. Is the right server selected over there?

Comment: @BalusC Yes, in server Runtime there is checked Apache Tomcat 8. I added the JAR manually just to test if that was the problem, though it was obvious a redundancy since it was already included (first screenshot)

Comment: Well, apparently Eclipse project config is messed up. What's all set in *Project Facets* property? Does it work if you create a new *Dynamic Web Project* from scratch and select the right server during the wizard?

Comment: @BalusC I created a new project (dynamic web), selected Tomcat 8 runtime, copied Home.jsp, and the error is not present there. I copied the project from a work colleague, because we both are trying to learn. Maybe there was the problem. Is there a way to "re build" the config? The web.xml differs from one project to other, there must be something! I added a 3rd picture with the diffs

Comment: You COPIED the project? Thus also including project's `.settings` folder? Don't do that. You'd better export and import as WAR instead.

Comment: @BalusC thanks... how do you do when you version the code... will the .settings be also included there, will it generate conflict?

Comment: Exclude it in .ignore file of version control system.